# Apache Directory Server Password History

Tags: apacheds

I have a problem with Apache Directory server password policy. It mentioned in ApacheDS documentation that the password policy is active by default. I have configured the policy to keep history of (5 previous) passwords and when a user tries to change it (with any of the existing passwords), there should be a "invalid reuse of password present in password history" exception generated, however ApacheDS dos not generate the exception.

The password policy entry is as below:

```
dn: ads-pwdid=default,ou=passwordPolicies,ads-interceptorId=authenticationInterceptor,ou=interceptors,ads-directoryServiceId=default,ou=config
objectclass: ads-passwordPolicy
objectclass: ads-base
objectclass: top
ads-pwdattribute: userPassword
ads-pwdid: default
ads-enabled: TRUE
ads-pwdcheckquality: 1
ads-pwdexpirewarning: 600
ads-pwdfailurecountinterval: 30
ads-pwdgraceauthnlimit: 5
ads-pwdinhistory: 5
ads-pwdlockout: TRUE
ads-pwdlockoutduration: 0
ads-pwdmaxage: 3888000
ads-pwdmaxfailure: 5
ads-pwdminlength: 8
ads-pwdmustchange: TRUE
ads-pwdsafemodify: FALSE
ads-pwdvalidator:org.apache.directory.server.core.api.authn.ppolicy.DefaultPasswordValidator
```

If someone can throw any light on it, it shall be very helpful

Comment: I think this is not reproducible against trunk version `M21`. What version of ApacheDS do you use?

Comment: I am on M20, the exception is not generated from Studio as well as from Apache DS LDAP API, is there any configuration that I am missing, I really don't know